# How to completely close postgresql transaction idle on Flask and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm developing the application with flask and sqlalchemy using PostgreSQL as RDB.
I'm curious PostgreSQL doesn't teardown transaction idle when request finisheed.

Here's code for teardown PostgreSQL transaction on flask:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(r):
    db.dispose()
    session.close()
```

But still I can see process of idle transaction for PostgreSQL.

```
$ ps axu | grep postgres
postgres 18127  0.9  1.0 326348  6612 ?        Ss   11:08   0:00 postgres: postgres mydb ::1(59013) idle
```

How can I terminate the process in application code?

Answer (score 6):

What you're seeing isn't a transaction, it's a session with no open transaction.

Most systems pool connections to save on the cost of setting them up and tearing them down for each and every transaction. Most likely you're seeing a connection that's held in the pool on the SQLAlchemy side, waiting for more work.

So long as it's not idle *in a transaction* that's just fine.

To control this behaviour, [tune SQLAlchemy's connection pool](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html).

Check `pg_stat_activity` for more details, rather than relying on `ps`.